# pathos pools: Renew worker processes after N tasks

Tags: python, pathos, process-pool

I am building a parallel python application, that essentially calls a C wrapper around an external library. Parallelism is needed to be able to run simultaneously computations on all CPU cores.

I ended up using `pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessPool`, but these pools lacks the `maxtaskperchild` argument of the standard `multiprocessing.Pool` class constructor ([see reference here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) ). I need this feature because the C library relies on the process clock to define some execution time limits, that are eventually reached when the tasks pile up.

**Is there a way to ask the `ProcessPool` manager to renew worker processes after a given number of tasks ?**

Example code to clarify my intent:

```py
from pathos.pools import ProcessPool
from os import getpid
import collections

def print_pid(task_id):
    pid = getpid()
    return pid

if __name__ == "__main__":
    NUM_TASKS = 50
    MAX_PER_CHILD = 2


    # limit each process to maximum MAX_PER_CHILD tasks
    # we would like the pool to exit the process and spawn a new one
    # when a task counter reaches the limit
    # below argument 'maxtasksperchild' would work with standard 'multiprocessing'
    pool = ProcessPool(ncpu=2, maxtasksperchild=MAX_PER_CHILD)
    results = pool.map(print_pid, range(NUM_TASKS), chunksize=1)

    tasks_per_pid = dict(collections.Counter(results))
    print(tasks_per_pid)

# printed result
# {918: 8, 919: 6, 920: 6, 921: 6, 922: 6, 923: 6, 924: 6, 925: 6}
# observe that all processes did more than MAX_PER_CHILD tasks
```

#### what I tried

- setting the `maxtasksperchild` in the `ProcessPool` constructor (cf naive example above) does not seem to do anything
- calling `sys.exit()` in worker function makes the program hang
- I have found hints when diving into the source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `pathos.multiprocessing` there are two pools:
`ProcessPool` and `_ProcessPool`.  The former is designed to have an augmented pool lifecycle that minimizes start-up time, and has persistence and restart capabilities -- however, lacks some of the "`multiprocessing`" keywords. The latter (`_ProcessPool`) is one level of API design down, and provides an interface that is identical to the `multiprocessing` `Pool` interface (but uses `dill`).  So, take a look at the `_ProcessPool`.

Comment: thanks, and kudos for maintaining this library! Does `_ProcessPool` have a chance to disappear in the future, since it is not documented ?

Comment: There is no chance for it to disappear in the future.  It actually shows up in two other places as the exact same object... if you look in `pathos.pools`, it's `_ProcessPool` there as well, and both modules import `pathos.helpers.ProcessPool as _ProcessPool`.  The `pathos` `ProcessPool` is built on top of it, it's not going away.